# React native animation of a View from side to side

Tags: react-native

I'm working with the animation of react-native lately and I'm trying to make a `View` component moving from side to side by click.
This is the code I have so far that works :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isLeftSide: true,
    }
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  animate () {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
      this.animatedValue,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start()
  }

  fire = () => { 
    this.animate();
    this.setState({isLeftSide: (!this.state.isLeftSide)});
  }

  direction = () => this.state.isLeftSide ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';

  render() {
    const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
    const objectMaxCoord = screenWidth - 40;

    const outputRange = {
      rtl: [0, objectMaxCoord],
      ltr: [objectMaxCoord, 0]
    }
    const marginLeft = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: outputRange[this.direction()]
    })
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.fire()}><Text>Run</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            marginLeft,
            height: 30,
            width: 40,
            backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 30
  }
});
```

Now, the problem is that the red cube starts on the left side, but as I click run, it jumps (without animation) to the right corner and then move smoothly(in animation) to the left side. what comes after that works just perfect. Why is this first jump happens ?

And is there any easier way to make this animation done ?

( P.S I'm working on android )
Here is a link to an expo
https://snack.expo.io/S1aAgNq6Z

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the state might not update right away. Try to change your fire function like this:

```
this.setState({isLeftSide: (!this.state.isLeftSide)}, () => {
   this.animate();
});
```

setState accepts a callback when done.

I was playing with a Snack for a while and the issue is clearly that the state gets unsync because it says is on the left side when actually is on the right. I don't see anything else messing with the state.

You can see it here: https://snack.expo.io/BJhb4-pAW

The snack is somehow limited so can you try this on your code?

```
 finishedAnimation = (finished) => {
    if (finished)
      this.setState({isLeftSide: !(this.state.isLeftSide)});
  }

  fire = () => { 
     this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
      this.animatedValue,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(this.finishedAnimation);
  }
```

Comment: still, it starts on the left and then jumps right and slide all the way to the left (on initial run)